# Does the "Simple predicate" include parts of phrasal verbs?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, predicate

A simple predicate is just the verb in the complete predicate.

So are the adverbial particles of the verb part of the simple predicate?

For example, "of" in "consist of" is it part of the simple predicate?
Likewise is "after" part of the simple predicate in "look after"?

Comment: The simple predicate is the verb itself.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Is there any source I could refer to? I'm thinking of the Cambridge grammar of the english language by   Pullum and Huddleston but I do not have a copy. I'll check Google books if they have a searchable copy.

Comment: @Peter ( grammar : an adverb or preposition that when combined with a verb creates a phrasal verb ▪The phrasal verb “look up” consists of the verb “look” and the adverbial particle “up.”) Merriam Webster. So I wonder why the change from particle into prepositions?

Comment: @learner I have changed it back, apologies, I misunderstood your intent.

Comment: @learner It's such a basic question that Swan and CGEL don't seem to address it, at least as far as I can tell. Hopefully my answer below sounds authoritative enough to use as your source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *simple predicate* is the *verb* or the essential parts of the *verb phrase* —the parts which cannot be omitted without changing the meaning—in a sentence. In a sentence with a simple verb, the *simple predicate* is easy to identify:

> She **looked** up at the sky.

In a sentence which contains an auxiliary or linking verb, the simple predicate also includes them:

> She **was looking** up at the sky.
>   She **has been looking** up at the sky.

In a sentence which contains a *phrasal verb,* the essential parts of the phrasal verb are also part of the simple predicate:

> She **looked up** his phone number in the directory.
>   She **was looking forward to** calling him.

Even when the parts of a phrasal verb are separated by other words, they are part of the simple predicate:

> She **was looking** his phone number **up** in the directory.